# Default Ip address of raspbian for orange pi zero

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have boot image file of raspbian for orange pi zero, but because there is no display port I should connect to it via direct cable network. But there is no information about the ip.

Comment: How do you connect? To a router? Directly with your ethernet port? Wifi?

Comment: Welcome, could you explain *I should connect to it via direct cable network* . Please.

Comment: There is no router. It connected directly to PC

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below link explaining how to connect to the orange pi zero under the section "Booting your Orange Pi Zero".

https://lucsmall.com/2017/01/19/beginners-guide-to-the-orange-pi-zero/

It appears that the device is configured to use DHCP initially and it will just get assigned an IP via your router, you should be able to see the device listed on your router in the DHCP table as described via the link.

Same result for Raspian Server:

https://www.sigmdel.ca/michel/ha/opi/domopiz_03_en.html#InstallRaspian

"the Ethernet interface will obtain a dynamic IP address from the dhcp server on the LAN"

Another alternative is trying to connect via USB using the com port in putty, please see this article on stack overflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48557666/orange-pi-zero-obtain-ip-without-accessing-router-interface

However for simplicity I suggest connecting to a router with DHCP enabled to configure a static IP to the device and then you can connect to it without the requirement of a router using the IP you define.

Comment: I have seen this page. It speaks about the Armbian. And also uses router. While I am seeking for solution to connect it directly via Ethernet